# How to normalize an angle between two limits?

Tags: math, angle

Using `Fmod`, I am able to restrict the calculated angle between **[0, maxLimit]**.

But how do we limit the same angle between **[minLimit, maxLimit]** ?

Answer (score 1):

Normalize to [0, abs(maxLimit - minLimit)] and then subtract minLimit.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution,

[0, abs(maxLimit - minLimit)] and add the minLimit.